# Javascript - Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am developing a project to create a visualization in d3. 
I have an array which has the filenames that are to be loaded in sequence.

But, when run through the array and call the respective methods, the second element in the array is called much before the first one has even finished loading.

```
        for(j=0;j<chosenAirports.length;j++)
        {
            var fileName = chosenAirports[j];
            var splitData = fileName.split("_");                
            readFile(splitData[0],selectedYear,splitData[0] + "_" +  selectedYear);
         }
```

readFile is the function that I am trying to call for each of the array elements. But before readFile for one element is completed, the next one in the loop is getting called.

And I believe this is due to the async feature of javascript.
Can anyone suggest a method by which i can avoid this.

ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you've gone ahead and messed with all of our heads by using the name `readFile()`, can we see what your `readFile()` actually does? We can't make any assumptions or provide help if the function is a blackbox with no details on input, output, or what it does internally.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're reading a file I guess that this is running on Node?

If so then the `readFile` function is either calling Node's `readFile` function or *is* Node's `readFile` function.

As you stated, this is an async function. There is a synchronous version of this called `readFileSync` that will prevent the problem that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to make the code work, using the synchronous `readFileSync()` method will fix your issue (Details here: https://code-maven.com/reading-a-file-with-nodejs).

If you're interested in ensuring asynchronous functions return but still run asynchronously, you may be interested in working with RxJS Promises.

Comment: I am afraid I lead you all in a wrong direction. The readFile does not stand for reading from a file. It is just the name of a function which does some specific task (nothing related to files). Sorry for not providing complete information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay asynchronous - and I suggest you do as there is no need to fight against what is core to Node/Javascript - you could wrap the processing of a file inside a Promise: create a function which take a file name as a parameter and whic returns a promise with the processing result.

Something like:

```
function processFile(fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data){
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      };
      return resolve(processData(data));
    });
  });
}
```

Obviously, you would need to provide your `processData()` function and make sure it returns the data for the processing of the given file.

Then, to chain the processing of all the files in order, you can use the `reduce` method on the array like:

```
const promise = chosenAirports.reduce((promise, fileName) => {
  return promise.then((previousResult) => {
    return processFile(fileName);
  })
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Then you query the result of this promise to get the final result.

```
promise
.then((result) => {
  console.log('Result: ', result);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

It is up to use to process the data and implement a mechanism to collect all the results, but not difficult with that solution.